# Snowflake rest api integration

Tags: api, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**I need to load data to snowflake from a rest api url, so i needed a guidance as i'am new to api stuff.**
I have tried loading that data to a local machine and then loading to snowflake through internal stage loading but it doesn't seem to me as an optimal solution.

Comment: Snowflake can't load data from an URL, but from a location in the form of an internal stage or external stage. This is documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-overview.html)

Comment: If it's not a ton of data, maybe you can create an external function to call the API and then use that as a source for an INSERT command.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-introduction.html 
not sure if this will work or not, but can't hurt to research it a bit.